# User granted privilege on base table so access to views already created is permitted?

Tags: sql, database, privileges

User is granted access to base table by the owner so will user have access to views already created on that base table?
Owner O
User u2
Table (..)
View v1 (partial view on table)
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON table to u2 WITH GRANT OPTION

Now will u2 have access to view v1?

Comment: In Oracle - no: "table" and v1 are different oblects

Answer (score 1):

In PostgreSQL you need to grant permission on the view if you want to use it. 
Grants on the table and the view are not related.